# Is there an `\firsthline` option for longtable?

Tags: longtable

I've been trying to use a command as `\firsthline` within a `longtable` environment.

`\cline` does not work, neither `\toprule` does.

This is my code example:

```
\begin{longtable}{lp{99mm}}
    \caption{Work plan schedule for the dissertation}\\
        \textbf{Work week} & \centering \textbf{Observations}\\
        %\firsthline\\
        \endhead

\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
   [every calendar/.style={
       month label above left,
       month text={\textit{\%mt, \ \%y0}},
       week list}]
   \calendar[dates=2013-07-01 to 2013-07-last];
\end{tikzpicture}}

&

Some text here\\

\label{tab:Schedule}
\end{longtable}
```

If I change the `%\firsthline` for `\hline` I get the following errors:

> pdflatex > ! Misplaced \noalign
>
> pdflatex > ! Misplaced \omit
>
> pdflatex > ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Comment: `\firsthline` is used for adjusting the vertical alignment of a `tabular` environment when the `[t]` option is used. It has no meaning for `longtable`, as far as I can see, because `longtable` doesn't make a box. In any case you need `array` for `\firsthline` and `booktabs` for `\toprule`

Comment: @egreg Yeap, I know firsthline does not work, but what could be a workaround?

Comment: @MarioS.E. just use `\hline`

Comment: @egreg, I get an error if I use \hline (see updated question).  Any other ideas?

Comment: `\centering` changes the meaning of ``\\``; either put it in a group (``{\centering\bfseries Observations\par}\\``) or simply use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Observations}`. There shouldn't be ``\\`` after `\hline`

Comment: @MarioS.E. If you want a spaced heavy rule, load `booktabs` and use `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]`

Comment: @egreg, setting {\centering \textbf{Observations}} did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @MarioS.E. Without the `\par`? I'm surprised. Indeed it produces left alignment. If the cell has only one line, `\multicolumn` is easier; why looking for complicated solutions when simple ones are available?

Comment: @egreg, without \par the column title stops being centered, but no error is displayed.  Using \par works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `\firsthline` and `\hline` is in the position of the reference point for a `\begin{tabular}[t]` so that text on the same horizontal line as the table aligns on its top row not on the line. However `longtable` is a vertical mode display construct so there can be no text on the same horizontal line, so you only need `\hline`.

Comment: How do I get the amazing capability of firsthline to give some space?  Should I just "hammer" it with vspace?

Comment: Your suggested use of `\firsthline` is _mid_ table which is not ever the intended use. Any space it makes in that position in a `tabular` is purely accidental. Where do you want space: above the line or below it?

Comment: David, I get an error.  See the updated question

Comment: You shouldn't have `\\ ` after `\hline` (or after `\firstline`)

Comment: Also you need  `\centering\arraybackslash \textbf{Observations}\\` if you use `\centering` in the last column as it changes the meaning of `\\ `